# MSVC - boost::python static linking to .dll (.pyd)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, static, linker, boost-python

I got a VS10 project. I want to build some C++ code so I can use it in python. I followed the boost tutorial and got it working. However VS keeps to link boost-python-vc100-mt-gd-1_44.lib but it's just a wrapper which calls boost-python-vc100-mt-gd-1_44.dll. That's why I need to copy the .dll with my .dll(.pyd) file. So I want to link boost:python statically to that .dll(.pyd) file. But I just can't find any configuration option in VS or in the compiler and linker manual. The weirdest thing is I've got one older project using boost::filesystem with the very same config but that project links against libboost-filesystem-*.lib which is static lib so it's ok. I've been googling for couple of hours without any success and it drivers me crazy.

Thanks for any help or suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What libraries are linked depends on the settings of your project. There are two possibilities: You can build against

1. statically
2. dynamically

linked versions of the c-runtime libs. Depending on which option is selected, the boost sends a proper `#pragma` to the linker. These options need to be set consistently in all projects which constitute your program. So go to "properties -> c++ -> code generation" (or similar, I am just guessing, don't have VS up and running right now) and be sure that the right option is set (consistently). Of course, you must have compiled boost libraries in required format before...

Comment: Boost is builded with settings: link=static link=shared threading=single threading=multi variant=debug variant=release runtime-link=static runtime-link=shared so everything should be there. In the VS if I set C++>CodeGeneration>Runtime="static" I got an error "fatal error C1189: #error :  "Mixing a dll boost library with a static runtime is a really bad idea...".

Comment: Hm, for some reason boost still assumes you are want to link with it's dlls. Do you really have all versions of boost libraries in the installation directory? You can see it from the naming scheme. I am not sure if the options you wrote out above are compatible. With `--build-type=complete` you are on the safe side. You need to set `C++>CodeGeneration>Runtime="static"` for all projects and for the runner. Then, boost configuration system should select the right version of the libraries. Otherwise, you can select the required linkage with `#define`s, check boost manual.

Comment: Hi, I really didn't know what is the purpose of the #pragma before. I searched headers and found /boost/python/details/config.hpp to call #pragma to request that .dll. I tried to comment it and requested my static .lib, however it didn't work. Then I saw checking for "#define BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB" in this header and defined it in my source. No it links ok. (but this define is commented as deprecated).

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to do that. Statically linked Boost python has a number of problems and quirks when there are more then one boost python based library imported. "But I only have one" you say. Can you guarantee that your users won't have another? That you might want to use  another in the future? Stick with the DLL. Distributing another DLL is really not that big a deal. Just put it side-by-side in the same directory.

Comment: Interesting point. Just for curiosity, what kind of problems and quirks do you mean?

Comment: Basically, the process has 2 copies of the BP type table. Libs that are meant to work together can't because they can't see the other's RTTI. More memory is used, for code and data, etc. The details depend on OS and everything else.